# Exploring $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^p}{n!} = B_pe$, particularly $p = 2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, soft-question, online-resources, set-partition

I was exploring the fact that $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^p}{n!} = B_pe,$$
where $B_n$ is the $n$th Bell number.

I found this result by exploring the series on wolframalpha and looking up the sequence of numbers generated. I have no experience with Bell numbers other than knowing that they represent the number of ways of partitioning a set.

**What I tried**

Looking at the base case we can verify
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)!} = e. $$

But then I realize that $n^2$ is going to be difficult.

**Specifically what I want**

I am doing this for fun, so I just want to glean some sort of lesson out of this. Resources that let me learn for myself are just as good!

An accepted answer will have any **one** of the following:

- **A proof that $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{n!} = 2e$ (this interests me a lot)**
- A description of why this series is related to Bell numbers and the number of partitions of a set
- A link to some resource that introduces Bell numbers and/or their connection to this series.

Comment: Hi Chantry. Your first two questions are completely answered below.

Comment: **Hint:** Since $n!~=~1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots(n-1)~n$, an obvious approach would be rewriting $n^2$ as $n~(n-1)+n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that
\begin{align}
    S
& = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{n^{2}}{n!} \\
& = \frac{0^{2}}{0!} + \frac{1^{2}}{1!} + \frac{2^{2}}{2!} + \frac{3^{2}}{3!} +
    \cdots \\
& = \frac{1}{0!} + \frac{2}{1!} + \frac{3}{2!} + \frac{4}{3!} + \cdots.
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
    S - e
& = \left(
    \frac{1}{0!} + \frac{2}{1!} + \frac{3}{2!} + \frac{4}{3!} + \cdots
    \right) -
    \left(
    \frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots
    \right) \\
& = \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{2}{2!} + \frac{3}{3!} + \cdots \\
& = e. \qquad (\text{As shown in the OP.}) \\
\end{align}
Therefore, $ S = e + e = 2 e $.

---

In fact, using the same type of reasoning, it can be shown that $ \displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{n^{3}}{n!} = 5 e $.

---

Here is the connection with Bell numbers.

For each $ p \in \mathbb{N}_{0} $, let $ \displaystyle S_{p} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{n^{p}}{n!} $. Notice that
\begin{align}
\forall p \in \mathbb{N}: \quad
    S_{p}
& = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{n^{p}}{n!} \\
& = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{p}}{n!} \qquad
    \left( \text{As $ \dfrac{0^{p}}{0!} = 0 $.} \right) \\
& = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{p - 1}}{(n - 1)!} \qquad
    (\text{After canceling $ n $’s.}) \\
& = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(n + 1)^{p - 1}}{n!}. \qquad
    (\text{After re-indexing.})
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
\forall p \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}: \quad
    S_{p} - S_{p - 1}
& = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(n + 1)^{p - 1}}{n!} -
    \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{n^{p - 1}}{n!} \\
& = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
    \frac{1}{n!} \left[ (n + 1)^{p - 1} - n^{p - 1} \right] \\
& = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
    \left[ \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k = 0}^{p - 2} \binom{p - 1}{k} n^{k} \right]
    \qquad (\text{By the Binomial Theorem.}) \\
& = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{k = 0}^{p - 2}
    \binom{p - 1}{k} \frac{n^{k}}{n!} \\
& = \sum_{k = 0}^{p - 2}
    \left[ \binom{p - 1}{k} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{n^{k}}{n!} \right] \\
& = \sum_{k = 0}^{p - 2} \binom{p - 1}{k} S_{k}.
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
\forall p \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}: \quad
  S_{p}
= \sum_{k = 0}^{p - 2} \binom{p - 1}{k} S_{k} + S_{p - 1}
= \sum_{k = 0}^{p - 1} \binom{p - 1}{k} S_{k}.
$$
As $ S_{0} = S_{1} = e $ by inspection, we see that the $ S_{p} $’s are the Bell numbers multiplied by $ e $.

Comment: Wonderful! This looks like it extends well to higher cases too - we can use that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^p}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{p-1}}{n!}$ and then expand the $(n+1)^{p-1}$ term to get that sum in terms of various sums of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^{p'}}{n!}$ in terms of lesser $p'$ (which implies some recurrence relation I don't feel like writing out).

Comment: @Meelo: Yes, there exists a recurrence relation. I once had to derive it in a high-school exam.

Answer (score 1):

Recall  the species  of set  partitions with  the  constituents marked
which is
$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{P}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}))$$
which gives the generating function
$$G(z, u) = \exp(u(\exp(z)-1)).$$

It follows that the exponential generating function of Bell numbers is
given by
$$G(z) = \exp(\exp(z)-1).$$

Suppose we are trying to compute
$$\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{n^p}{n!}.$$

Put $$n^p = \frac{p!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{p+1}} \exp(nz) \; dz.$$

Observe that this gives $n^p = 0$ when $n=0$ except when $p=0$ as well.

We get for the sum
$$\frac{p!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{p+1}} 
\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{\exp(nz)}{n!} \; dz
= \frac{p!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{p+1}} 
\exp(\exp(z)) \; dz
\\ = \exp(1) \times \frac{p!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{p+1}} 
\exp(\exp(z)-1) \; dz
\\ = \exp(1)\times B_p$$
as claimed.

Comment: This is a little beyond my current understanding. I do not know what $\mathfrak{P}$ (power set maybe?) stands for and have little understanding about generating functions and contour integrals. Thank you for your contribution though! I will be sure to return to your answer in the future after studying both subjects.