# Sum of the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^k}{n!}$, aka Dobinski's formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the sum of the following series? $k$ is a natural number.

> **$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^k}{n!}$**

It appears to always provide an integer multiple of $e$.

Comment: Are you asking what the sum of the infinite series is? What do you mean the series is an answer? What work have you done on the problem, and where are you stuck? What is the context of the problem?

Comment: Yes, it always provide a integer multiple of $e$, and more, the secuence of those integers is called Bell numbers.

Comment: This same question appeared at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242818/).

Answer (score 10):

Let
$$A(k) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^k}{n!}.\tag{1}$$
Since:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{e^{nx}}{n!} = e^{e^x}-1 \tag{2}$$
we have:
$$ A(k) = \frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left.\left(e^{e^x}-1\right)\right|_{x=0} = B_k\cdot e\tag{3}$$
where $B_k$ is a [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number). $(3)$ is also known as [Dobinski's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski%27s_formula).

Comment: This is a surprisingly interesting answer for such a terrible question.