# Evaluating a simple series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am having a little trouble with simple computation.

What is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{k!}$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242818/exploring-sum-n-0-infty-fracnpn-b-pe-particularly-p-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^2}{k!}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^2}{k(k-1)!}$$
 $$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{(k-1)!}$$$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k-1)+1}{(k-1)!}$$$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k-1)}{(k-1)(k-2)!}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k-1)!}$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k-2)!}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k-1)!}$$$$=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k-2)!}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k-1)!}=e+e=2e$$