# Hint for finding the $\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{n^p}{n!},p \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hint for finding the $\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{n^p}{n!},p\in \mathbb{N} $

I would appreciate a hint or several hints if I can solve this problem in different ways.

Comment: See [Dobiński's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobiński%27s_formula)

Comment: See also [Exploring $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^p}{n!} = B_pe$, particularly $p = 2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1242818)

Comment: Thanks guys, wonderful tips.